# creating dynamic height

Tags: html, css, height

While trying to create a div 'ed structure I am having difficulty on covering a background color.
in the example below the wrap div is not covering other layers.
There is something I am missing in the css but cannot figure out what is the problem :(
Any help would be great :)

```
<style type="text/css">
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: Arial;
}
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background: #688420;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, Geneva, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000;
}
#column {
    position: relative;
    width: 950px;
    margin: auto;
}
#wrap {
    background-color:#FF0;
}
.wrapleft {
    background-color: #039;
    text-align: left;
    float:left;
    width:60%;
}
.wrapright {
    background-color:#3F9;
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
    width: 35%;
}
.seperator {
    width:5%;
    background-color:#9CC;
    float:left;
}
.space {
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
    clear:both;
}
#wrapContent {
    background-color: #C3F;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="main">
    <div id="column">
        <div id="wrapContent">
            <div id="wrap">
                <div class="space">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="wrapleft">
                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam a sem risus. Suspendisse ullamcorper iaculis pellentesque. Aenean urna urna, fringilla at semper id, placerat cursus urna. Morbi tempor, orci sed elementum tempor, velit felis elementum dui, sit amet suscipit lorem sapien id nulla. Praesent molestie consequat erat, nec dictum lorem vehicula non. Aenean sodales lacinia tincidunt. Sed semper ornare augue ut malesuada. Etiam ac ornare mauris.  </p>
                </div><!-- wrapleft -->
                <div class="seperator">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="wrapright">
                                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam a sem risus. Suspendisse ullamcorper iaculis pellentesque. Aenean urna urna, fringilla at semper id, placerat cursus urna. Morbi tempor, orci sed elementum tempor, velit felis elementum dui, sit amet suscipit lorem sapien id nulla. Praesent molestie consequat erat, nec dictum lorem vehicula non. Aenean sodales lacinia tincidunt. Sed semper ornare augue ut malesuada. Etiam ac ornare mauris.  </p>
                </div> <!-- wrapright -->
                <div class="space">&nbsp;</div>
                                <div class="wrapleft">
                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam a sem risus. Suspendisse ullamcorper iaculis pellentesque. Aenean urna urna, fringilla at semper id, placerat cursus urna. Morbi tempor, orci sed elementum tempor, velit felis elementum dui, sit amet suscipit lorem sapien id nulla. Praesent molestie consequat erat, nec dictum lorem vehicula non. Aenean sodales lacinia tincidunt. Sed semper ornare augue ut malesuada. Etiam ac ornare mauris.  </p>
                </div><!-- wrapleft -->
                <div class="seperator">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="wrapright">
                                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam a sem risus. Suspendisse ullamcorper iaculis pellentesque. Aenean urna urna, fringilla at semper id, placerat cursus urna. Morbi tempor, orci sed elementum tempor, velit felis elementum dui, sit amet suscipit lorem sapien id nulla. Praesent molestie consequat erat, nec dictum lorem vehicula non. Aenean sodales lacinia tincidunt. Sed semper ornare augue ut malesuada. Etiam ac ornare mauris.  </p>
                </div> <!-- wrapright -->


            </div><!-- wrap -->

    </div> <!-- column -->
</div> <!-- main -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to clear your floats:

```css
#wrap {
    background-color:#FF0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! it worked :) I have tried to add div's with class of clear:both but it did not workout so well. Well, again thank you!